# Sonos - Seek API returns 'ERROR_DISALLOWED_BY_POLICY'

Tags: node.js, sonos

I tried using the "Seek" API (/playbackSessions/{sessionId}/playbackSession/seek) to seek to a certain time within the track (that is loaded from an Amazon S3 bucket, not within the local network), and received the following error: "ERROR_DISALLOWED_BY_POLICY ".
In the reference it's mentioned that this occurs due to "scrubbing is not allowed".
How can I "allow scrubbing"?
I've also noticed that "Resume" (after pause), is playing the track from the start. So, my guess is that Pause/Resume/Seek is only allowed within the network. Is that the case? Any way to pause & resume a track, or seek a certain time, while using a track "outside" of the local network (A CDN link as Amazon-S3 bucket files)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Playback policies are set by the content provider. In the case of Cloud Queue-based playback, these policies are set in the /context or /itemWindow responses, as described [here](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/play-audio/set-playback-policies/).

Comment: I tried to set a policy on to the playback entity, without any luck (still getting the "ERROR_DISALLOWED_BY_POLICY"). Can you please provide an example of how to set it up.
Thank you, Tal.

Comment: Getting "ERROR_DISALLOWED_BY_POLICY" when using the seek command.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: How are you trying to set the playback policy. Control of policies is documented here: https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/play-audio/set-playback-policies/